# jQuery .each command not working

Tags: jquery

i want following code to run in one of the paegs in my joomla website. this code simply opens a form when user clicks on forth column with associated first name and ....  i added this code to the end of my joomla article HTML directly in phpmyAdmin so js codes wont be filtered.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery(".oldPeople tr:not(.oldPeople tr:first)").each(function (i) {
        //code
        jQuery(this td:nth-child(4)).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        jQuery(this td:nth-child(4)).click(function () {
            var fname = jQuery(this td: nth - child(1)).html();
            var lname = jQuery(this td: nth - child(2)).html();
            var dep = jQuery(this td: nth - child(3)).html();
            var str = encodeURI("http://alumsharif.org/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=38&form[fname]=" + fname + "&form[lname]=" + lname + "&form[dep]="dep);

            jQuery(this td:nth-child(4)).replaceWith(str);
            window.open(str);
        }); //click
    }); //each
}); //ready
```

and the web page is :
http://alumsharif.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=230&Itemid=2011

but the code doesnt work.. when i put console.log inside each function nothing happends... i dont know if i have missed sth or not...

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: i cant find any missing )

Comment: Because it is a `+` that is missing: `...+ "&form[dep]="dep);` -> `...+ "&form[dep]=" + dep);`

Comment: And the "selectors" in `jQuery(this td:nth-child(4))` are also wrong

Comment: Whats wrong abt selectors?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for silly and basic errors in my code:
i corrected my code and publish it in case anyone need it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

jQuery(".oldPeople tr:not(.oldPeople tr:first)").each(function(i) {
//code
var tr = jQuery(this);
jQuery(this).children("td:nth-child(4)").css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
jQuery(this).children("td:nth-child(4)").click(function(){
 var fname = tr.children("td:nth-child(1)").text();
  console.log(fname);

var lname = tr.children("td:nth-child(2)").text();
var dep = tr.children("td:nth-child(3)").text();
var str = "http://alumsharif.org/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=38&form[fname]="+encodeURI(fname)+"&form[lname]="+encodeURI(lname)+"&form[dep]="+encodeURI(dep);
 //jQuery(this).children("td:nth-child(4)").replaceWith(str);
 window.open(str,' ارسال اطلاعات' + fname + " "  +lname, 'width=600, height=600');
 console.log(str);
  });//click
 });//each


});//ready
```